# Can't edit MySQL row

Tags: php, sql

Hello all so I'm trying to allow the user to edit their data after they've submitted it. I have a staff table set up with an auto-incrementing primary key. It's this bit of my code that's giving me bother `//getting id from url
$StaffID = $_GET['StaffID'];` I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with it because the syntax seems correct. It's telling me the indexed is unidentified.

```
<?php
// including the database connection file
include_once("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{   
    $StaffID = $_POST['StaffID'];



    // checking empty fields
    if(empty($Name) || empty($Address) || empty($Telephone) || empty($BusinessID)) {           
        if(empty($Name)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($Address)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Age field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($Telephone)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Email field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }  

        if(empty($BusinessID)){
            echo "<font color='red'>Email field is empty.</font><br>/";
        }
    } else {   
        //updating the table
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE staff SET Name='$Name',Address='$Address',Telephone='$Telephone', BusinessID='$BusinessID' WHERE StaffID = $StaffID");

        //redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
        header("Location: HomePHP.php");
    }
}
?>
<?php
//getting id from url
$StaffID = $_GET['StaffID'];      // <---- ERROR

//selecting data associated with this particular id
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE StaffID=$StaffID");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{


    $Name = $res['Name'];
    $Address = $res['Address'];
    $Telephone = $res['Telephone'];
    $BusinessID = $res['BusinessID'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first change your syntax to prevent SQL injection. I guess your problem will then be solved.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE staff SET Name= ?, Address= ?, Telephone= ?, BusinessID= ? WHERE StaffID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param( "sssii", $Name, $Address, $Telephone, $BusinessID, $StaffID);   
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. In the Update part do i keep the '?' and where would you place the suggested bit of code?

Comment: Yes you keep the '?', the  '?' are binded with the variables in the next line. Just replace it with your line of code "$result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE staff ..."

Comment: Thankyou very much for the help. I'm learning alot. It's still, unfortunately, giving me an Unidentified index error on the line. 

//getting id from url
$StaffID = $_GET['StaffID'];

Comment: What is the URL your are calling? Is your syntax for StaffID is equal to the parameter in your URL?

Comment: So my update.php is called by when the user has hit the edit button on a page, taken to a new page allowed to input new changes and then the update.php should work.